# Logging exception before handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have following problem. The async entity framework functions produce a `TaskCanceledException` when cancelled. I am catching this exception and deal with it appropriately. However the exceptions still get logged which I do not want.

Simplified setting:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route( "page" )]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPage(
    int? page, int? size,
    CancellationToken ct)
{
    try {
        var response = await _mailService.GetPageAsync( page, size, ct: ct );
        return Respond( response ); // Turn service response into HTTP response
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        // When reaching here, Exception already logged
        // If it should be cancelled
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
            // Empty result
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        else {
            // Else raise again
            throw; // Never reached
        }
    }
}
```

I also pass the `CancellationToken` into all the async entity framework operations. I tried catching the exception right around the entity function

```
try {
    page = query.ToListAsync( ct );
catch(TaskCanceledException){
    // When reaching here, Exception already logged
    return null; 
}
```

But same behavior. As soon as it enters the catch-block the Exception already got logged.

For logging I use Serilog with this configuration

```
var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext();
    // Add Sinks

// Create Logger
Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();


// Configure()
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

Is there a way to handle this differently or should I suppress the `TaskCanceledExceptions` in the log?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think EF is logging the exception.

Comment: You can see it here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbContext.cs#L351

Comment: Is there anyway to configure EF to not log those or suppressing globally only option?

Answer (score 1):

based on comment from @juunas. You can hide the logging by overwriting this method (thank god its virtual)

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        
        CheckDisposed();

        TryDetectChanges();
        
        //remove try catch to throw without logging.
        return await StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Remember you now copy pasted some of EF code inside your repo. this means if you update entity framework it could be this method's body has changed and thus your code breaking entity framework.

So be warned.

## solution 2 hiding logs from EF

the other solution would be is to log no errors of entity framework at all setting loglevel: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore : "None"` inside the Logging configuration appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The exception actually comes from a `ToListAsync()` and not a `SaveChangesAsync()`. I ended up filtering all `TaskCanceledExceptions` in Serilog.