# Skip logging Entity Framework caught exceptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging

```cs
try
{
    using var c = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    c.Entities.AddRange(entities);
    c.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case InvalidOperationException:
        case DbUpdateConcurrencyException:
        case DbUpdateException when (
            e.InnerException is PostgresException pe &&
            pe.SqlState == "23505"):
            HandleException();
            break;

        default: throw;
    }
}
```

In this code example, Entity Framework (EF) logs exceptions that occurred calling `SaveChanges` before the exception is caught.

Instead, I want to manage the caught exception and log as needed, and leave it to the default behavior of EF (logging the exceptions) for the uncaught exceptions.

The exceptions read as the following:

```
[15:25:47 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (31ms) [Parameters=[@p0=...], , CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO ... 
RETURNING xmin;

[15:25:47 ERR] An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type ... 
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 23505
...
```

A [solution suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42487116/947889) for a similar question is to disable all the logging of EF, however, I'm interested in leaving the default behavior untouched for the uncaught exceptions, and ideally not modifying the logging configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Serilog you can supress all of EF's "error" level logs with config by logging only fatal and above:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Fatal"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If your EF errors are bubbling up and being handled/logged in the normal way you shouldn't lose anything other than EF's over-active logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own methods for handling the events, so you can buffer them all and process them after the fact.  EG in your DbContext:

```
bool ShouldLog(EventId eid, LogLevel l)
{
    return true;
}
void CaptureEvent(EventData eventData)
{
    loggedEvents.Add(eventData);
}
List<EventData> loggedEvents = new List<EventData>();

public IEnumerable<EventData> GetEvents( LogLevel MinLogLevel)
{
    return loggedEvents.Where(e => e.LogLevel >= MinLogLevel);
}
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=efCore6Test;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true", o => o.UseRelationalNulls(true))
        .LogTo(ShouldLog, CaptureEvent);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does not answer my question, unfortunately, (a) `Failed executing ...` is logged before `ShouldLog` is even called; (b) it leads to filtering a decent amount of logging information and I'm concerned about its performance penalties; (c) it leads to defining logging filtering in two places: at logger definition (`MinimumLevel.Override(...)`) and at defining connection string. Is `UseRelationalNulls` relevant here?

Comment: Maybe I missing something here, but why EF is logging exceptions before throwing them?!